# Help with my First workflow

Tags: workflow, document-set, task-list, workflow-designer

Hey Sharepoint Experts,

As a school project we are working for a non profit organisation. We are trying to build a SharePoint site for them.
One module they want to see implemented is a module wich creates evolution reports.

The cases they are working on are document sets on their sharepoint. 6 months after the creation of a case (document set) they are obligated to make an evolution report. 6 months after the 1st evolution report they need to make a new evlution report, this keeps repeating until the case is set as "closed" (a column in the document sets is used to indicate it is closed). every case is assigned to an employee (sharepoint user)

They want some kind of reminder when a new evolution report needs to be made and also want an overview of what cases still need an evolution report and what cases are overdue.

my thought was to make this by using  a workflow but my knowledge is a litte small.What i'm trying to do is have a loop where it creates a task every 6 months to make an evolution report. The loop ends when the statusfield in the documentset "cases" is put on stop!.
Here is what I have at this moment. I'm kind of new making workflows so any tips or help would be appreciated[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In addition to document sets, I'd recommend you maintain a list of cases. Case records can have a date field which keeps Next Evaluation Report date, and a yes/no field named "Evaluation Completed" with a default value of no, workflow checks if "Evaluation Completed" and if it is yes, sets Next Evaluation Date to today + 6 months (and set itself back to No).

In terms of reminders, I usually use a view of this table, filtering records with Evaluation dates which are less than [Today]+7 (so the ones in the next 7 days and everything in the past - overdues). Call this view Reminders and put it on the landing page.

You can also do e-mail reminders but it gets a bit more complicated. I daily crawl through the list to see which items are outstanding and sending an e-mail to the assigned person.

Comment: Hey Charles Thank you so much for this answer! Is there anyway I could contact you If I run into more trouble ? !